# Tomcat with Java 11 deploy issue

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat9

I've deployed a WAR with JAXB which relies on javax.activation libs but after deploy I persistently get a ClassNotFoundError that javax.activation.DataSource cannot be found.

I tried adding the javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar to Tomcat/lib folder and also in WEB-INF/lib but still same error.

If I downgrade to Java 8, Tomcat deploys well no errors.
Also it works OK in windows 7(but not with Redhat Linux).

Any idea how to investigate this type of issue or what could the cause be?

Error:

```
18/12/17 17:34:07.290 [Thread-0]            ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.error[98] - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[InternalEngine].StandardHost[internalhost].StandardContext[internal]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at com.swift.aws.server.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:409)
        at com.swift.aws.App.<init>(App.java:142)
        at com.swift.aws.App.start(App.java:524)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[InternalEngine].StandardHost[internalhost].StandardContext[internal]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initFactory(ProviderFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ServerProviderFactory.createInstance(ServerProviderFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setupFactory(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:182)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:531)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:1042)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4788)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5100)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Post the full error...

Comment: added error in description